# What do model.predict() and model.fit() do?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm going through [this reinforcement learning tutorial](http://outlace.com/Reinforcement-Learning-Part-3/)
and It's been really great so far but could someone please explain what

```
newQ = model.predict(new_state.reshape(1,64), batch_size=1)
```

and

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batchSize, nb_epoch=1, verbose=1)
```

mean?

As in what do the arguments `bach_size`, `nb_epoch` and `verbose` do?
I know neural networks so explaining in terms of that would be helpful.

You could also send me a link where the documentation of these functions can be found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it surprises me that you could not find the [documentation](http://keras.io/models/model/) but I guess you just had bad luck while searching.

The documentation states for [`model.fit`](http://keras.io/models/model/#fit):

> `fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, callbacks=[], validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None)`
>
> - `batch_size`: integer. Number of samples per gradient update.
> - `nb_epoch`: integer, the number of times to iterate over the training data arrays.
> - `verbose`: 0, 1, or 2. Verbosity mode. 0 = silent, 1 = verbose, 2 = one log line per epoch.

The `batch_size` parameter in case of `model.predict` is just the number of samples used for each prediction step. So calling `model.predict` one time consumes `batch_size` number of data samples. This helps for devices that can process large matrices quickly (such as GPUs).

Comment: I had actually been to that website but didn't know where to look in it

I'm beginner :/

Answer (score 0):

Here are definitions for fit() and predict() methods.

The fit() method takes the training data as arguments, which can be one array in the case of unsupervised learning, or two arrays in the case of supervised learning

Essentially, predict() will perform a prediction for each test instance and it usually accepts only a single input (X)

Comment: `predict()` takes the same input shape like `fit()`. `predict()` doesn't accept a single sample input.